# How to add JSON String to an HTTP request header?

Tags: swift, http, request, alamofire

This is my request function:

```
static func request(url:String, method: HTTPMethod, parameters: [String:AnyObject], completion: @escaping (Optional<AnyObject>) -> (), errorBlock:@escaping (String, Int) -> (Bool)){
    let url = URL(string: "\(kAPIHostname)\(url)")!
    var req = URLRequest(url: url)
    
    req.httpMethod = method.rawValue
    req.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: [])
    
    APIManager.process(request: req, completion: completion, errorBlock: errorBlock)
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to add to the request header all of the `parameters` instead of the body here.

Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if parameters dictionary of headers, than add this code before or after **req.httpBody = ...**

```
var headerParameters: [String: String] = [:]
for header in parameters {
     headerParameters[header.key] = (header.value as? String ?? "")
}
req.allHTTPHeaderFields = headerParameters
```